# Is there any method of converting math formula in java

Tags: java

I need to convert that formula in such a way that i can make the calculation by taking the input of radix and number from user

```
〖log〗_radix (number)=  (〖log〗_e (number))/(〖log〗_e (radix))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate a math expression given in string form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Comment: I doubt there's any engine that can convert your example. Best to make your own.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Are you asking for the java code that computes the result after asking the user for input? As the other folks rather think you want to take that formula, and have that parsed and evaluated and whatnot (which is orders of magnitudes more complicated)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, you could simply read the inputs similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642352/how-do-i-read-input-that-could-be-an-int-or-a-double). Then, just calculate the result.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
double number = input.nextDouble();
double radix= input.nextDouble();

double result = Math.log(number) / Math.log(radix);
```

Comment: Please explain your downvote.

Comment: Your answer seems right to me, someone else downvotes the answer

Comment: Does it work? If yes, could you mark the answer as correct?